# Как выключить фильтр текста в SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, google-speech-recognition

У меня есть вот этот код, который переводит из аудио в текст и отправляет в телеграмм, используя библиотеку Aiogram. Но проблема в том, что он фильтрует плохие слова (бл***)
Как можно отключить этот фильтр?

```
file_audio = sr.AudioFile(abs_file_path)

with file_audio as source:
    audio_text = r.record(source)

await get_message(r.recognize_google(audio_text, language="ru-RU").lower(), message.from_user.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе надо открыть `__init__.py`  (speech_recognition),

найти

```
def recognize_google(self, audio_data, key=None, language="en-US", show_all=False):
```

и отредактировать на

```
def recognize_google(self, audio_data, key=None, language="en-US", show_all=False, pfilter=1):
```

Дальше
найти

```
url = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?{}".format(urlencode({
            "client": "chromium",
            "lang": language,
            "key": key,
        }))
```

и отредактировать на

```
url = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?{}".format(urlencode({
            "client": "chromium",
            "lang": language,
            "key": key,
            "pFilter": pfilter,
        }))
```

и сделать

```
r.recognize_google(audio_text, language="ru-RU", pfilter=0)
```

Comment: Чувак спасибо! Не смотря на то что прошёл месяц, мне всё еще нужен был ответ :D